# Html5 support having SelectAll for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

i have the following Razor view inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr id="@item.RouterID">
        <td>

 <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxSelection" 
                               value="@item.RouterID.ToString()"
                                /> 
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Router", new { id=item.RouterID },null)
```

Which will display a checkboxes inside table rows. so does Html-5 support having SelectAll checkbox , for selecting all the checkboxes that have the same name or id ?
Thanks

**Edit**
i add the following selectAll checkbox:-

```
<input type="checkbox" 
                               name="selectAll"
                id="selectAll" 

                                />
```

and i wrote the following script:-

```
$('body').on("change", "#selectAll", function () {
    var checkflag = "false";
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('CheckBoxSelection');
    function check() {
        if (checkflag == "false") {
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
            checkflag = "true";

        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                field[i].checked = false;
            }
            checkflag = "false";

        }
    }
});
```

but it did not work,, i mean the checkboxes will never get checked/unchekced .. can anyone adivce?

Comment: will need to do that with javascript

Comment: can you see my edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a checkbox for Select All / Deselect All

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" name="selectAll" />
```

Add a css class named "checkBoxClass"

```
foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr id="@item.RouterID">
        <td>

 <input class='checkBoxClass' type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxSelection" 
                               value="@item.RouterID.ToString()"
                                /> 
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Router", new { id=item.RouterID },null)
}
```

In jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectAll").click(function () {
        $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```